# Google Closure Namespace Clash

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a JavaScript module that is compiled using Google Closure.  This module needs to be included in a web page that also includes some 3rd party unrelated code.

The problem is both pieces of code are using the namespace "com" so: com.companyone.x.y.z and com.companytwo.x.y.z

It seems that closure compiler is automatically generating the code to create the name space like so:

```
var com = {mycompany: {}};
```

And therefore overwriting anything else that has previously used the com namespace.

If I were to write this by hand I'd check if the namespace exists first like so:

```
var com=com||{};
com.mycompany=com.mycompany||{};
```

As temporary solution I'm thinking of automatically replacing the "var com={" with "var com=com||{" but it seems hacky.

Is there a way to ensure the Closure Compiler doesn't wipe the overwrite the existing com namespace?

Comment: Are you using the compiler's AMD/CommonJS support?

Comment: You need to post code so that we can reproduce the issue. As it currently stands you have not provided enough information. This would include not only Javascript, but also the compilation flags you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to isolate your definitions to interfere as little as possible with other ones.

```
--output_wrapper    (function(){%output%})()
```

This will create a new lexical scope for the variables. For example:

```
var com = 'example';
(function() {
     var com = {mycompany: {}};
})();
```

The `com` inside the scope does not affect the one outside it.

If you need to reference global variables -- like, say, the global `com`, use `goog.global`:

```
 goog.global.com
```

If you need to "export" your variables to the global scope, you can use `goog.exportSymbol`. This will preserve already defined namespaces.

---

Though I'm actually unsure of cases where the compiler would generate the code you posted; an example would be helpful.